# webRTC videocall, remote stream is blank when call answered but no errors thrown. Where has the video gone?

Tags: reactjs, webrtc

I'm trying to implement a video call in a react web app using Firebase to manage offers and answers. When I run the app and start a call through localhost and join the call in another tab, everything works as it should. However when I try to join a call on a different device, the local stream comes up on screen but there is no remote stream for either user.
I'm only new to using webrtc and react so I am lacking in knowledge, any help is appreciated

```
componentDidMount() {
    const firestore = firebase.firestore();

    const servers = {
        iceServers: [
            {
                urls: ['stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302', 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'],
            },
        ],
        iceCandidatePoolSize: 10,
    };

    // Global State
    const pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
    let localStream = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }).then(stream => this.videoTag.current.srcObject = stream)
        .catch(console.log);;;
    let remoteStream = null;

    // HTML elements
    const webcamButton = document.getElementById('webcamButton');
    const webcamVideo = document.getElementById('webcamVideo');
    const callButton = document.getElementById('callButton');
    const callInput = document.getElementById('callInput');
    const answerButton = document.getElementById('answerButton');
    const remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');
    const hangupButton = document.getElementById('hangupButton');

    // remoteVideo.play();

    webcamButton.onclick = async () => {
        localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
        remoteStream = new MediaStream();

        // Push tracks from local stream to peer connection
        localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
            pc.addTrack(track, localStream);
        });

        // Pull tracks from remote stream, add to video stream
        pc.ontrack = (event) => {
            event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach((track) => {
                remoteStream.addTrack(track);
            });
        };

        webcamVideo.srcObject = localStream;
        remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;
        //webcamVideo.play();
        callButton.disabled = false;
        answerButton.disabled = false;
        webcamButton.disabled = true;
    };

    // 2. Create an offer
    callButton.onclick = async () => {
        // Reference Firestore collections for signaling
        const callDoc = firestore.collection('calls').doc();
        const offerCandidates = callDoc.collection('offerCandidates');
        const answerCandidates = callDoc.collection('answerCandidates');

        callInput.value = callDoc.id;

        // Get candidates for caller, save to db
        pc.onicecandidate = (event) => {
            event.candidate && offerCandidates.add(event.candidate.toJSON());
        };

        // Create offer
        const offerDescription = await pc.createOffer();
        await pc.setLocalDescription(offerDescription);

        const offer = {
            sdp: offerDescription.sdp,
            type: offerDescription.type,
        };

        await callDoc.set({ offer });

        // Listen for remote answer
        callDoc.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            const data = snapshot.data();
            if (!pc.currentRemoteDescription && data?.answer) {
                const answerDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(data.answer);
                pc.setRemoteDescription(answerDescription);
            }
        });

        // When answered, add candidate to peer connection
        answerCandidates.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
                if (change.type === 'added') {
                    const candidate = new RTCIceCandidate(change.doc.data());
                    pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
                }
            });
        });

        hangupButton.disabled = false;
    };

    // 3. Answer the call with the unique ID
    answerButton.onclick = async () => {
        const callId = callInput.value;
        const callDoc = firestore.collection('calls').doc(callId);
        const answerCandidates = callDoc.collection('answerCandidates');
        const offerCandidates = callDoc.collection('offerCandidates');

        pc.onicecandidate = (event) => {
            event.candidate && answerCandidates.add(event.candidate.toJSON());
        };

        const callData = (await callDoc.get()).data();

        const offerDescription = callData.offer;
        await pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offerDescription));

        const answerDescription = await pc.createAnswer();
        await pc.setLocalDescription(answerDescription);

        const answer = {
            type: answerDescription.type,
            sdp: answerDescription.sdp,
        };

        await callDoc.update({ answer });

        offerCandidates.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
                console.log(change);
                if (change.type === 'added') {
                    let data = change.doc.data();
                    pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(data));
                }
            });
        });
        //remoteVideo.play()
        console.log(remoteVideo)
    };

}

render() {

    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
                <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href={<svg width="410" height="404" viewBox="0 0 410 404" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M399.641 59.5246L215.643 388.545C211.844 395.338 202.084 395.378 198.228 388.618L10.5817 59.5563C6.38087 52.1896 12.6802 43.2665 21.0281 44.7586L205.223 77.6824C206.398 77.8924 207.601 77.8904 208.776 77.6763L389.119 44.8058C397.439 43.2894 403.768 52.1434 399.641 59.5246Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)" />
                    <path d="M292.965 1.5744L156.801 28.2552C154.563 28.6937 152.906 30.5903 152.771 32.8664L144.395 174.33C144.198 177.662 147.258 180.248 150.51 179.498L188.42 170.749C191.967 169.931 195.172 173.055 194.443 176.622L183.18 231.775C182.422 235.487 185.907 238.661 189.532 237.56L212.947 230.446C216.577 229.344 220.065 232.527 219.297 236.242L201.398 322.875C200.278 328.294 207.486 331.249 210.492 326.603L212.5 323.5L323.454 102.072C325.312 98.3645 322.108 94.137 318.036 94.9228L279.014 102.454C275.347 103.161 272.227 99.746 273.262 96.1583L298.731 7.86689C299.767 4.27314 296.636 0.855181 292.965 1.5744Z" fill="url(#paint1_linear)" />
                    <defs>
                        <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="6.00017" y1="32.9999" x2="235" y2="344" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                            <stop stop-color="#41D1FF" />
                            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#BD34FE" />
                        </linearGradient>
                        <linearGradient id="paint1_linear" x1="194.651" y1="8.81818" x2="236.076" y2="292.989" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                            <stop stop-color="#FFEA83" />
                            <stop offset="0.0833333" stop-color="#FFDD35" />
                            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFA800" />
                        </linearGradient>
                    </defs>
                </svg>
                } />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
                <title>WebRTC Demo</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h2>1. Start your Webcam</h2>
                <div class="videos">
                    <span>
                        <h3>Local Stream</h3>
                        <video id="webcamVideo" autoPlay playsInline muted="muted"></video>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <h3>Remote Stream</h3>
                        <video id="remoteVideo" autoPlay playsInline></video>
                    </span>


                </div>

                <button id="webcamButton">Start webcam</button>
                <h2>2. Create a new Call</h2>
                <button id="callButton" disabled>Create Call (offer)</button>

                <h2>3. Join a Call</h2>
                <p>Answer the call from a different browser window or device</p>

                <input id="callInput" />
                <button id="answerButton" disabled>Answer</button>

                <h2>4. Hangup</h2>

                <button id="hangupButton" disabled>Hangup</button>

            </body>
        </html>

    )
}
```

Comment: This may be an issue with lac of turn server configuration. Also most of the free turn servers shouldn't work . Check ICECandidate status using this link https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/

If you are using chrome you can also check chrome://webrtc-internals for what happening inside RTCPeerConnection

Comment: https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/perfect-negotiation-in-webrtc/ , this will give you a clear picture about perfect negotiation in webRTC

Comment: @BijuKalanjoor That solved it! Changed the server config and set up a  turn server, thanks for your help!